# Matrix question help.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} 7 &  10 \\
                          15  & 22 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Find a real matrix $A$ for which $A^2 = X$. 
I don't know how to answer this or where to start.

Comment: One way is to note that $X$ is diagonalizable, with positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Indeed! But that might be too advanced given the nature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Write

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix} a^2+bc & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot \end{bmatrix}.$$

I'll let you work out the expressions that should go into the dots inside the matrix.  Then solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: So I set each part of the matrix A^2 to the corresponding part of x. How am I suppose to solve for each letter with so many variables in each equation

Comment: It's no fun but not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

A surprising result is that the square root of a 2 x 2 matrix can be constructed, it is not unique, and since it involves two very relevant functions of a matrix I think it's worth presenting :
$$ M=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $ a + d =   tr(M) $ ,   $ ad - bc =  Det M $

$ s^2 = Det M $ , $ t^2 =  tr(M) + 2s $

Then $ R = \frac{1}{t}\begin{bmatrix} a+s & b \\ c & d+s \end{bmatrix} $  is a square root of the matrix M.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix

Comment: I like that....